# Category Redirection

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have a requirement to implement redirection rule from one category to home page. can we achieve this by writing category redirection rule using impex or what could be the solution ?

Thanks so much in advance.

Regards,
Jagdish

Answer (score 0):

We can redirect in categoryPageController. Check for the category and redirect to Home.